# Help Gödel with his β function

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory

Gödel's β  function takes three natural numbers as arguments.

It is defined as `β(x,y,z) = rem(x, 1 + (z + 1) · y) = rem(x, (z · y + y + 1) )`

where rem(a, b) denotes the remainder after integer division of a by b.

The β Lemma now states that:

> For any sequence of natural numbers (k_0, k_1, … , k_n), there are natural numbers b and c such that, for every i ≤ n, β(b, c, i) = k_i.

Gödel needs help to find `b` and `c` for any given input `(k_0, k_1, … , k_n), k_i ∈ ℕ`.

---

Write a function that takes in an array of length `n`, filled with natural numbers, and gives a possible `b,c` output that fulfilles the Lemma for the array.

---

Do not get solutions by brute force!

(In my totally unprofessionall opinion, it is brute force when you first get a number and then do the calculation. That is guessing the number and then looking if the guess was correct. What I want to be coded here is a solution which calculates the numbers and does not have to check whether they fulfill the lemma because they were calculated to do so. )

Construct them with the equations and information given.
Shortest code wins, bonus points if you do it in `Javascript` because I am just getting into it `:)`

---

Example:

```
[5, 19, 7, 8] -> (1344595, 19)
1344505 % (1 + (0 + 1) * 19) = 5
1344505 % (1 + (1 + 1) * 19) = 19
1344505 % (1 + (2 + 1) * 19) = 7
1344505 % (1 + (3 + 1) * 19) = 8
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a nice first question, but I would recommend adding some test cases to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi. I didnt add any tests because there are sometimes different ways to solve for one array. If I gave an input-output pair it could seem like this input had to give this output.

Comment: @Tweakimp Even so, a single worked example could help clarify the rather formal definition.

Comment: You are saying "shortest", does it means a brute force solution is just ok? although there is some constructive solutions

Comment: @tsh You are right, I should clarify that brute force solutions are not allowed, because that would take away the nice construction problem :)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48057/194)

Comment: It's not clear what qualifies as "brute force". Obviously an approach which iterates through all pairs `(b, c)` until it finds one which works would be brute force, and an approach which runs in time linear in the length of the input would not be, but there's a large gap between those. Where is the line drawn?

Comment: @PeterTaylor i think "solve it in P" is acceptable (not brute force), while we assume your math operations (add, mul, rem...) on two number are O(1).

Comment: @PeterTaylor This is significantly more complicated than the related challenge, as the moduli are not (co)prime here.

Comment: @MartinEnder I added an example I generated with my answer.

Comment: Did someone say Beta?

Comment: @orlp, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12110/194 . PS Who says they're not coprime? That's one of the questions hidden behind my question about what qualifies as brute force...

Comment: @Peter Taylor: In my totally unprofessionall opinion, it is brute force when you first get a number and then do the calculation. That is guessing the number and then looking if the guess was correct. What I want to be coded here is a solution which calculates the numbers and does not have to check whether they fulfill the lemma because they were calculated to do so.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just realized that for some (non-optimal) `c` it doesn't have to be not coprime. But for some `k` the optimal `c` leads to not pairwise coprime moduli.

Comment: I think `%`, the modulo operator, is more widely known than `rem`. It works the same way: `a%b` returns the same thing as `rem(a,b)`. Your call, but I recommend using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 104 bytes

```
a=>[c=a.reduce(c=>c*++i,Math.max(...a),i=0),a.reduce(g=(x,k)=>x%m-k?g(x+n,k):(n*=m,m+=c,x),0,n=1,m=c+1)]
```

Returns `[c, b]` as an array. The solution it returns isn't minimal in `c` but I think it is minimal in `b` for the given `c`. For 120 bytes this returns solutions minimal in `c` and in `b` for the given `c`:

```
f=(a,c=1,b=a.reduce(g=(x,k)=>x%m-k?d--?g(x+n,k):0/0:n%m?g(x,k,n+=o):(o=n,d=m+=c,x),0,o=n=1,d=m=c+1))=>1/b?[b,c]:f(a,c+1)
```

Ungolfed minimal solution solver:

```
function godel(a) {
    for (c = 0;; c++) {
        var b = 0, n = 1, i = 0;
        for (;;) {
            var m = c * i + c + 1;
            // Increase b until β(b,c,i) = a[i]
            // Adding n won't change output for smaller i
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) if (b % m != a[i]) b += n;
            if (j == m) break; // couldn't find a remainder, c too low
            i++;
            if (i == a.length) return [b, c]; // Result!
            // Next time we want adding n to b not to change β(b,c,i)
            for (j = 1; n * j % m != 0; j++);
            n *= j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Would you be so kind and comment the code? :)